# 504 Gateway Timeout on HTTPS but not HTTP

Tags: amazon-ec2, iis, ssl, amazon-web-services, load-balancing

I configured an AWS Load Balancer. It is working find on HTTP, but when I try over HTTPS I get a 504 Gateway Timeout Error. I tried all the suggestions on AWS's help page (increase idle timeout), but no luck. Any ideas why it wouldn't work over HTTPS, but still work over HTTP?

Both the Instance and Load Balancer security groups have HTTP and HTTPS enabled

The load balancer has HTTP and HTTPS listeners (note the LB does not terminate the SSL cert, it has 443 on front and back end port)

If I change it to be 443/80 (front/back) it works.

I do want it to be 443/443. But when I set it up this way I get the 504 error.

Comment: Is the instance listening on 443?

Comment: Yes.  Direct to instance (over IP) on 443 works.

Comment: What's in the instance logs to correspond with the 504s on the front end?  Note also, that 443 front and back *does not* mean the ELB is not terminating the SSL.  In fact, if you think it does, that is potentially part of the problem.

Comment: I understand that the LB is not terminating the SSL.  I was saying that was what I wanted.

Comment: There are no IIS logs when I get the 504s.  I don't even think traffic is getting to the server.

Comment: Is the certificate chain, which should include the trusted root CA for the server cert on your backend server, installed in the ELB?  That is, perhaps the one issue is that the ELB connections, over TLS, to the backend server are failing because the ELB is failing to properly verify/trust the backend server's certificate?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you've selected HTTPS as Instance protocol. I've had set 443 both as LB and instance ports but HTTP selected as Instance Protocol and exactly the same behaviour.